# How to reformat all cells in DataBindingComplete method?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I need to iterate all  rows/cells by name and replace value by condition in method: `DataBindingComplete`.

I tried to to this like as:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    string pass = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn45"].Value.ToString();
               dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn45"].Value = (pass == "1") ? "Повторно" : "Первый раз";
}
```

But there is no `e.RowIndex` property. How to do that?

Dont suggest me to use method `_CellFormatting`. It does not work for me, because I have got custom columns, that can be rendered by this method.

Also I tried this way:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e) {
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     intRow++;
     string pass = dataGridView1.Rows[intRow].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn45"].Value.ToString();

               dataGridView1.Rows[intRow].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn45"].Value = (pass == "1") ? "Повторно" : "Первый раз";
}
}
```

It returns an error:

> System.StackOverflowException occurred   HResult=0x800703E9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an index inside a foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0] is DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
    {
         string pass = ((DataGridViewTextBoxCell)row.Cells[0]).Value;
         ((DataGridViewTextBoxCell)row.Cells[0]).Value = (pass == "1") ? "Повторно" : "Первый раз";
    }
}
```

Comment: It give me an error: `'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell'.'`

Comment: I need to check by name and replace value.

Comment: You did not change answer

Comment: I replaced DataGridViewCheckBoxCell for DataGridViewTextBoxCell, still not working?

Comment: How to check additionally type and if text then replce?

Comment: It returns me another error: `  Message "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown." string
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152556/discussion-between-isma-c-and-opv).